# Singleton in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods

What does the following method actually do?

(This is created in an NSObject class.)

> ```
> + (MyClass *)sharedInstance
> {
>     static MyClass *sharedInstance;
>
>     static dispatch_once_t once;
>     dispatch_once(&once, ^{
>         sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
>     });
>
>     return sharedInstance;
> }
> ```

```
- (NSArray *)myArray {
    ....
}
```

Then in another class I would call `myArray` like this:

```
[[MyClass sharedInstance] myArray];
```

Does `sharedInstance` get called every time the above code gets executed? Also, how can I call `myArray` without initializing it first? (Note `myArray` is `-` not `+`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the regular implementation of the Singleton pattern. You have a static reference to a single instance of `MyClass`, allocated when you first call `+sharedInstance`.

`+sharedInstance` will indeed get called every time `[MyClass sharedInstance]` is executed, but that shouldn't be a problem. You also shouldn't need to call `-myArray` without using the singleton. You could do it by just allocating a local instance and call `-myArray` on it.

Comment: is instance type the same shared instance?

Comment: Yes, both the shared instance and any local one will be of the same `MyClass` class.

Comment: And, does "`(instancetype) init`" get called before all other methods?

Comment: You can see the call to init **inside** `+sharedInstance`. For a local instance/variable you would call init yourself ``[[MyClass alloc] init]`` before calling `-myArray`